# How to draw an elliptical arc with CoreGraphics?

Tags: core-graphics

Is it possible to draw an elliptical arc like SVG path, in CoreGraphics and how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into the same thing tonight.  CG doesn't offer an easy way to draw a non-circular arc, but you can do it using CGPath and a suitable transformation matrix.  Suppose you want an arc of an axis-aligned ellipse starting at left,top and with a size of width,height.  Then you can do something like this:

```
CGFloat cx = left + width*0.5;
CGFloat cy = top + height*0.5;
CGFloat r = width*0.5;

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(cx, cy);
t = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, height/width), t);
CGPathAddArc(path, &t, 0, 0, r, startAngle, endAngle, false);
CGContextAddPath(g->cg, path);

CGContextStrokePath(g);

CFRelease(path);
```

Note that if you want to draw a pie-shaped wedge, then just surround the "CGContextAddPath" call with a CGContextMoveToPoint(cx,cy) and a CGContextAddLineToPoint(cx,cy), and use CGContextFillPath instead of CGContextStrokePath.  (Or if you want to fill and stroke at the same time, use CGContextDrawPath.)

Comment: Works great - NB: don't make the mistake I made :). the CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation is *required* even if you're using MoveToPoint (because the transform t has to be applied while the curve is at the origin, or else Apple's scale transform will ALSO multiply your offset from the origin!)

Comment: Note that will also scale the stroke width.